# Log4j2 - cannot access ListAppender

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I'm creating Spring-Boot application with Log4j2.
Libraries that I use are:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1

Class **ListAppender** cannot be found in these jars.
When I try to import: **org.apache.logging.log4j.test** there is an info: "Cannot resolve symbol...", like there is no package like this. But I can see in github:
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/test/appender/ListAppender.java
that it exists.

What is the source of problem? Am I doing everything in right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the path of the URL shows, `ListAppender` is in `/src/test`, which means it is an internal class used only for testing Log4J itself, not for your use.

The fact that you tried to import a package named `test` would also be a hint that you're trying to use "test" code.

Comment: So do you mean that there is no possible to use ListAppender? I saw some tutorial that describes how to use it: https://relentlesscoding.com/2018/04/21/unit-test-log4j2-log-output/

Comment: If you're using maven looks like the key thing would be including the `test-jar` type like in the blog

Comment: @skywatcher As Aarjav just said, add `<type>test-jar</type>` to the `<dependency>` for `log4j-core` just **like shown in the blog**.

Comment: Could you give me quick solution how to do it in gradle? What I have to add to: testCompile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'

Comment: Ok I got it I've just have to add: classifier: 'tests'

Thanks for help!